# How to drag and drop mp3 files to a listbox without the file path?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am having some problems with a media player made in C#, I had already asked for another problem here in stackoverflow, but now I have a different one and I think it's the last one.

I want to drag and drop MP3 and WAV files to a listbox in a windows form, I can drop them correctly, but I can't play them without showing the full path of the file.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
        foreach (string m in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m));
            mediaList.Add(m);
        }
```

**mediaList** is a list that helps me to save the playlist.
**listbox1** is my main playlist.

To play the songs I use this code, which has been working well 'til now:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = mediaList[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

Thanks in advance. -ChrisCreateBoss

Comment: Famous last words :)

>> I had already asked for another problem here in stackoverflow, but now I have a different one and I think it's the last one

Comment: xD, I mean that I think this is the last problem I will have with this project in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listbox items can contain objects.  Since you want to have access to the fullname, but display only the filename, this class will store the full name dropped, but only display the filename portion. These are handy when there are several bits of info to save for each item.

```
class FileItem
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public FileItem(string file)
    {
        FullName = file;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullName);
    }
}
```

The entire name is saved, but only the short name will display using the override.  When files are dropped, we will create FileItem objects from them.  Then there are 2 choices:
   a) place the objects in the ListBox and get rid of mediaList, or
   b) put the new items in medialist and use it as a DataSource

This will do the second since the mediaList is not glued to the UI.  Be sure to change `mediaList` as shown:

```
// new mediaList 
List<FileItem> mediaList = new List<FileItem>();
...
private void lb1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        mediaList.Add(new FileItem(f));
    }
    // tell the LB to display whatever is in mediaList
    lb1.DataSource = mediaList;
}
```

Rather than *2* copies of the files, whats in `mediaList` is also displayed in the `ListBox`; the `FileItem` objects in it will display just the short name.  Your original code should work with a tweak:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = mediaList[lb1.SelectedIndex].FullName;
```

Otherwise *without* the DataSource, you will need to cast `Items` back to a `FileItem` and use FullName to get the original full path name back:

```
FileItem fil = (FileItem) lb1.Items[lb1.SelectedIndex];
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = fil.FullName;

// or 
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = ((FileItem)lb1.SelectedItem).FullName;
```

Comment: When I try to play the song, it shows me this error: "Reference to object not established as an object's instance" (using the class and code you provided)

Comment: edit your post to show how you try to play it...that is not an actual error message either

Comment: Cannot convert int to type "MediaPlayer.Form1.FileItem" ??

Comment: Is there a way to add the full path to the mediaList and show the file name in the listbox? Because now I can just play the dragged files.

Comment: I just amended the answer for that - use mediaList as a Datasource - no need for 2 copies of the files (one in the LB, one in mediaList).  I had no idea what mediaList was when I first answered so I only mentioned DS.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I just need to show for example: "Get Lucky" in the listbox, and add "C:/Users/username/Documents/Data/Get Lucky.mp3" to the mediaList.

Comment: that is what the current answer does; exactly that using mediaList as a DataSource

Comment: so why I can just play the dragged files and not the ones that were there already.

Comment: I dont know what "the ones that were there" are or how you coded it.  Did you change mediaList to `mediaList<FileItem>`?  I assume it was List<string> before

Comment: Do you mean like this? `List<FileItem> mediaList = new List<string>();`

Comment: No.  That will not compile.  I showed how in the answer.

Comment: Ok, now I can play the other songs, but  when I drag files to listbox, they are not shown. Well, I gtg so I will continue on Sunday or Monday.

Comment: Hey, the dragdrop effects should be in .None or .Copy?

Comment: Sorry, that has nothing to do with the posted problem.  You should click the checkmark next to the answer and post a new question for new problems.

Comment: It is about the same problem, but after searching in google, I've found that many people writes this line of code :`DragDropEffects.Copy`

Comment: The post makes clear `I can drop them correctly` with title asking for help storing files to a `listbox without the file path`.  All done.